# Retrieve integer from django model field and add it to dictionary if it meets criteria

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm having trouble getting the code right for this project that I am working on...

Basically I have a function with some variables defined:

```
def mealSelect():
    calorielimit = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id).bmr
    breakfast = Breakfast.objects.all()
    lunch = Lunch.objects.all()
    dinner = Dinner.objects.all()
    snack = Snack.objects.all()
    breakfastcals = Breakfast.objects.value_list('calories')
    lunchcals = Lunch.objects.value_list('calories')
    dinnercals = Dinner.objects.value_list('calories')
    snackcals = Snack.objects.value_list('calories')
    todayscals = {}
```

What I am trying to do is:

- Retrieve a random object for each meal (breakfast, lunch, dinner and
  snack)
- If the random objects combined are less than the calorielimit append
  them to a dictionary with the keys Meal 1, Meal 2, Meal 3, Meal 4
- If the random objects combined exceed the calorielimit, continue
  until a combination is found that does not exceed the calorie limit
- Return the qualifying dictionary

Or if there's a better way to achieve a set of 4 objects below the calorie limit, the concept above is the way I tried and I just couldn't figure out how to make it work so I'm guessing there's probably an easier, more elegant way to get 1 model from each model that when combined are below the calorielimit.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you `Breakfast`, `Lunch`, `Dinner` and `Snack` models have a field called `cals` for calories

```
def mealSelect():
    calorielimit = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id).bmr
    totalcals = calorielimit + 1
    while totalcals > calorielimit:
       breakfast = Breakfast.objects.all().order_by('?')[0]
       lunch = Lunch.objects.all().order_by('?')[0]
       dinner = Dinner.objects.all().order_by('?')[0]
       snack = Snack.objects.all().order_by('?')[0]
       totalcals = breakfast.cals + lunch.cals + dinner.cals + snack .calls
```

Your meal plan is `breakfast`, `lunch`, `dinner` and `snack`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like :

- Pick a Breakfast randomly
- update the remaining calorielimit
- pick a Lunch randomly which has calories less than the updated calorielimit
- update the remaining calorielimit
- pick a Dinner randomly which has calories less then the updated calorielimit
- update the remaining calorielimit
- pick a Snack randomly which has calories less then the updated calorie limit

in Code it might look like this:

```
import random
def mealSelect():

    calorielimit = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id).bmr
    breakfast = random.choice(Breakfast.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit))
    calorielimit -= breakfast.caloriesbreakfast

    lunch = random.choice(Lunch.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit))
    calorielimit -= lunch.calories

    dinner = random.choice(Dinner.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit))
    calorielimit -= dinner.calories

    snack = random.choice(Snack.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit))

    return {"Meal 1": breakfast, "Meal 2": lunch, "Meal 3": dinner, "Meal 4": snack}
```

This might not work depending on the actual meals in general since for example Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner might already exceed the calorielimit. For this to work you would need to add every meal after retrieving it via `random.choice` to the dictonary, put everything within a while loop under the condition that all items of the dictionary are not None.

For this you'd also need a small custom function

```
import random

def defaultchoice(lst,default):
    try:
        return random.choice(lst)
    except IndexError:
        return default
```

With this my approach would look like treturn_dicthis :

```
def mealSelect():

    return_dict = {}
    while not all(return_dict.values()):
        calorielimit = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id).bmr

        breakfast = defaultchoice(Breakfast.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit), None)
        calorielimit -= breakfast.caloriesbreakfast
        return_dict["Meal 1"] = breakfast

        lunch = defaultchoice(Lunch.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit), None)
        calorielimit -= lunch.calories
        return_dict["Meal 2"] = lunch

        dinner = defaultchoice(Dinner.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit),None)
        calorielimit -= dinner.calories
        return_dict["Meal 3"] = dinner

        snack = random.choice(Snack.objects.filter(calories__lte=calorielimit), None)
        return_dict["Meal 4"] = snack

    return return_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the results from DB, and consolidate all the combinations of the meals and just pick at random a meal that meets your criteria.

```
from itertools import product

def mealSelect():
    calorielimit = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id).bmr
    breakfast = Breakfast.objects.values('calories', 'pk')
    lunch = Lunch.objects.values('calories', 'pk')
    dinner = Dinner.objects.values('calories', 'pk')
    snack = Snack.objects.values('calories', 'pk')

    allcals = product(breakfast, lunch, snack, dinner)  # create all combinations of the four meals
    allmeals = []  # desired list
    for item in allcals:
        if sum(i.get('calories', 0) for i in item) < calorielimit:
            allmeals.append(item)
    random_set = allmeals[random.randit(0, len(allmeals))]  #pick an index at random

    breakfast_item, lunch_item, snack_item, dinner_item = random_set
    breakfast_obj = Breakfast.objects.get(id=breakfast_item["id"])
    lunch_obj = Lunch.objects.get(id=lunch_item["id"])
    snack_obj = Snack.objects.get(id=snack_item["id"])
    dinner_obj = Dinner.objects.get(id=dinner_item["id"])
    return {"breakfast": breakfast_obj, "lunch": lunch_obj, "snack": snack_obj, "dinner": dinner_obj}
```